# Substituição de dados em listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def substituir(lista,velho,novo):
    lista = [1,2,3,3,5]
    resultado = substituir(lista[velho],novo)
    return resultado
```

O problema é que eu não consigo substituir um item velho da lista por um novo item.

Por exemplo se eu colocasse `substituir(lista, 2, 99)`

Índices com valor `2` seriam substituídos com o valor `99`

Exemplo:

Antes:

```
lista = [1,2,3,2,4]
```

Depois:

```
[1,99,3,99,4]
```

Comment: Por que você redefine `lista` dentro da função?

Comment: porque só seria alguns dados que estiverem o mesmo valor, não todos